# Mechanize: can't pass info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to pass `login` and `password` to the form textfields of the site.

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

agent.get("http://zenitbet.com/").forms.first

 => #<Mechanize::Form
 {name nil}
 {method "POST"}
 {action "index.php"}
 {fields
  [text:0x3fc34da544c0 type: text name: login value: ]
  [field:0x3fc34da5418c type: password name: imd5 value: ]}
 {radiobuttons}
 {checkboxes}
 {file_uploads}
 {buttons [submit:0x3fc34da53d90 type: submit name:  value: войти]}>
```

When I'm trying to pass info like

```
agent.get("http://mobile.zenitbet.com/").forms.first.login = "login"
agent.get("http://mobile.zenitbet.com/").forms[0].fields[1].value = "password"
```

and submit it

```
agent.get("http://mobile.zenitbet.com/").forms[0].submit
```

there is no changes: form doesn't submit and page doesn't redirect

What did I miss? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a fresh page each agent.get()

Try

```
agent.get("http://mobile.zenitbet.com/") do |p|
  f = p.forms.first
  f.login = 'login'
  f.password = 'password'
  f.submit
end
```